# Using on/off switch to get rid of UILabel in different viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, segue, uiswitch

What I'm trying to do is use a segue for a `UISwitch` so I can get rid of the `UILabel` called `phaselabel` on first view controller when the switch is off.

On first view controller I have:

```
import UIKit

class MeditationScreenViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var phaseLabel: UILabel!

func settingsDidChange(_ settings: MeditationSettings) {
    meditationSettings = settings
    session = MeditationSession(settings: settings, phaseChangedBlock: { [weak self] (phaseName) in
        debugPrint("Entering phase: \(phaseName)")
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        strongSelf.phaseLabel.text = phaseName
        switch phaseName {
        case "Breathe In":
            strongSelf.circleAnimation.animate(direction: CircleAnimationView.Direction.expand, time: TimeInterval(strongSelf.meditationSettings.breathIn))
        case "Breathe Out":
            strongSelf.circleAnimation.animate(direction: CircleAnimationView.Direction.contract, time: TimeInterval(strongSelf.meditationSettings.breathOut))
        default: break
        }
    }, timeChangedBlock: { [weak self] phaseTime, phaseTotal in
        self?.timeLabel.text = "\(Int(phaseTime)) / \(Int(phaseTotal))"
    }, completion: { [weak self] in
        debugPrint("Finished")
        self?.timeLabel.text = ""
        self?.phaseLabel.text = ""
        self?.startStopButton.isSelected = false
    })
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.phaseLabel.text = name
}
```

On second view controller I have:

```
import UIKit

var name: String = ""

class MeditationSettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var showCycleTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var showCycleTitleSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func showCycleTitleChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if (sender.isOn == true)
        {
            func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                if segue.identifier == "segue" {
                    if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MeditationScreenViewController {
                        name =
        }
        else
        {
            name = ""
        }
    }
```

I hope this isn't too complicated. I've used the `var name: String = ""` in second view controller so I can use it to grab the `phaseLabel` in first view controller.

Comment: What is the problem, what is not working? Please include a description of the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour as well in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I will do:-

I would define a variable in class `MeditationScreenViewController` which will store the value of the switch whether it is on or off.

```
class MeditationScreenViewController: UIViewController {

      var isSwitchOn: Bool!
}
```

and when calling the `prepareForSegue` I will store the switch value to `isSwitchOn` variable as you have access to the class variables after you cast the viewController as `MeditationScreenViewController`.

Code will look something like this:-

```
 @IBAction func showCycleTitleChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if (sender.isOn == true)
        {
            func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "segue" {
                if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MeditationScreenViewController {
                    sendToDetailViewController.isSwitchOn = sender.isOn

     }
}
  }
}
```

Finally in your `viewWillAppear` method in `MeditationScreenViewController` use the value to hide the label or not.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
if isSwitchOn == true {
    //unhide the label
   self.phaseLabel.isHidden = false
   //set your label value here
  }
    else {
     self.phaseLabel.isHidden = true
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details but this part isn't working: if segue.identifier == "segue" {
                if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MeditationScreenViewController {
                    isSwitchOn = sender.isOn

     }
}

Comment: Isn't not recognising the 'isSwitchOn' from the other ViewController and 'it says 'use of unresolved identifier "segue". Any ideas as this is a BOOL now and not a String? Thanks.

Comment: I missed out on a small detail.. see code now.. updated! I forgot to reference the variable using sendToDetailViewController

Comment: change isSwitchOn == sender.isOn to sendToDetailViewController.isSwitchOn = sender.isOn

Comment: Thanks but it still says 'use of unresolved identifier "segue".'

Comment: you need not to copy my code blindly. Here "segue" means your segue identifier/name string which you set in the storyboard. Put that string in place of "segue".

Comment: I think you removed the func prepareForSegue. Use my code as a reference and not a final solution. Anyways edited again :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the ViewController you want to receive the data

```
//create variable to store passed data from UISwitch
var switchStatePassed = [String]()

//perform tasks with passed data
```

In the other ViewController

```
fun prepare(for segue: UIStorybordSegue, sender: Any?) {
  //set destination to MeditationScreenViewController
  if let destination = segue.destination as? 
  MeditationScreenViewController {
   //check UISwitch state and create variable to store info
   if showCycleTitleSwitch.on {
    let switchState = "enabled"
   } else {
      let switchState = "disabled"
    }
   //send switchState to other ViewController
   destination.switchStatePassed = switchState
}
```